# How do I achieve availability when processing events in-order?

Tags: parallel-processing, message-queue, mq

### Goal

I want to implement resilient processing of events and still process them in the order in which they arrived.

### Description

A listener task listens to events of many clients, wraps them in a message and puts them in a queue. Event handler tasks read from the queue and process the events. Events of a single client must be processed in order; events of different clients can be processed out of order. A simple solution would be:

Create N queues, listener queues events in `queue[client_id % N]`. Each queue has a single event handler reading from it.

This works but I must also consider the case where an event handler fails. I can think of two ways to handle that:

1. Do leader election amongst readers of the queue - one election for each queue
2. Use RabbitMQ's Confirms feature (or the equivalent in other MQ systems) - every queue has several event handlers. An event handler dequeues a message and sends back a confirm once it has finished processing it.

### Problem scale

There are about 5K events/sec, events are small 50-200 bytes. A message in a queue will probably be a cluster of 1000s of events to reduce MQ overhead. This means that an MQ system that supports option 2 and handles dozens of messages/sec will work.

### Question

Can I do option 2 or will it there be too much contention on the queue? Is it even supported using confirms? Is there a better way to implement such a design? I can send clusters of events to event handlers and wait for an ACK before sending the next chunk but I think that using MQ is probably less reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I think you need a single, task specific queue. I don't know whether your MQ system supports such a thing. Another option to use one queue per client, it depends on your MQ system, how expensive a queue is, so it might work as well. If I were you, I would write an automatic test to measure.

Comment: Did you check ZeroMQ and nanomsg? They are good MQ systems as well, but work differently than RabbitMQ.

Comment: @inf3rno, I'm not using an MQ system but I'm considering it. I'll pick a system which has the features I need.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5680488/843660

Answer (score 1):

Another method of doing this is to use a [partitioned topic](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) in Kafka. Kafka can partition a topic by an identifier and maintain ordering inside a partition. So in this case it's good to partition by `client_id`. Then, Kafka manages the load between clients by repartitioning the topic.

Also see: [How to achieve distributed processing and high availability simultaneously in Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060261/how-to-achieve-distributed-processing-and-high-availability-simultaneously-in-ka?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I have used RabbitMQ before but cannot confirm if it supports your scenario of only delivering the next message when the first message is processed successfully, I'll leave that part to someone else with better knowledge in that tool.

for an implementation with any generic service/message bus:

A queue per event source could help in solving the problem with the help of the following technique:

- Have a pool of handlers (per queue, or generally that can process from all the queues if the event is the same), when a handler fails we still have many others, and we can instantiate as many or as few handlers to keep up with demand.
- Each queue should be locked while a event is being processed by a handler, to maintain the event order of processing.
- A locked queue should have a timeout to unlock automatically and recover the last event(that was locked), in case a handler picks an event and fails while processing it.
- A handler processing an event, after finishing, unlocks the queue and deletes the event that it just finished processing.

That technique is partially a peek-lock, but locks the whole queue, not just 1 event.

You will not gain more throughput with this approach, maybe more stability and resilience to failure, mainly because of the locking of queues. A better way is to think of how to remove the dependency on the order of messages and allow handlers to pick those messages in any order and still achieve the business logic needed (maybe [correlation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751435(v=vs.110).aspx) could help).

Answer (score 0):

First, I strongly believe that the most efficient way of processing requests sequentially is processing them by a single handler. Hence, the solution should provide an "affinity", so every client should be bind to a handler (as you described in your "simple" solution). We just had to create a dispatch routine, which is efficient and compatible with handler crashes.

How can an affinity be implemented? How can an affinity be reassigned if a handler has to be shut down?

As a key measure, I would offer to limit the length of handlers' queues and to keep exceptional load in one big "incoming" queue:

```
clients -> listener -> (big incoming queue) -> load balancer -> handler queues -> handlers 
                                                    \________<-__system events_<-____/
```

As soon as we have some guaranties on the length of a handler's queue (ex.: "a queue is short enough to be processed in 0.1s"), we obtain access to a wide range of "load balancing" methods, which may be unavailable in general case. The limit on queue size should be tuned as low as possible without losing performance.

The "Load balancer" routine should be able to:

1. maintain a bidirectional map (or ever a plain array) which assigns handlers to clients;
2. dispatch messages from incoming queue to handler queues according to the map;
3. receive notifications on handler idle (then unbind clients from this handler)
4. receive notifications on handler death (then redistribute clients from this handler);
5. recycle the queue of a dead handler (if data loss is not permitted)

In such architecture, logic would be highly customizable. For example, we would get a variety of choices how to implement a "queue overrun" (a situation when a handler queue has reached its limit):

- stop entire processing
- kill handler and redistribute its queue
- get to know (in some way, for example by means of time limits or by counters in shared memory) that the handler queue doesn't contain any requests from this client, then reassign the client;
- postpone request in some way;
- ban the client; etc.

My offer is not a high-tech solution, it is more like do-it-yourself programming. But I guess such design would be scalable and efficient enough to achieve high availability.