# Is there a message queue system that supports 10k topics?

Tags: real-time, message-queue

We have a problem like this:

We have jobs consistently coming from a queue. 
These jobs are of different types, and different types of jobs are processed at different speed. We are processing these jobs concurrently, so we don't demand jobs processed in order, so strictly we don't need a FIFO queue. In fact, blocking one type of jobs because of the slowness of another type of jobs is not allowed.

If we can create a topic for every type of jobs, then the problem is solved. But the problem is that we have so many types of jobs, potentially 10k of them.

Currently we are preparing to build a "queue" system for this problem, perhaps on top of a database. But using a DB as a queue is considered as anti-pattern by a lot of people.

Is there any message queue system that can handle 10k topics (or subtopics)?

One of the requirement is that the consumer side need change the topics it subscribes consistently. So if takes a lot of

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: perhaps relevent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680488/